# Api call possible for this data structure?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

**Concept behind data structure**

In a game room users can set themselves eligeable for a `Battle` with a maximum number of slots. On the one side there is one `SuperHero` versus a multitude of `BadGuy`s. A `BadGuy` can pick up a booster to make him temporarily stronger in a battle.

**Note**:
Bear in mind that this is a simplified version that concentrates on the relationships between models (because that is where my problem lies), there are more fields in reality.

**Current data structure**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Battle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Battle '{0}'".format(name)

    def get_contestant_from_user(self, user):
        if user == self.superhero.user:
            return self.superhero
        elif user in self.bad_guy_set.all():
            return self.bad_guy_set.get(user=user)
        else:
            raise Exception("User '{0}' is not a contestant in "
                            "this battle".format(user.__unicode__()))


class Contestant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class SuperHero(Contestant):
    battle = models.OneToOneField(battle)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Super hero '{0}' of {1}".format(self.user, self.battle)


class BadGuy(Contestant):
    battle = models.ForeignKey(battle)
    has_booster = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "One of the bad guys '{0}' of {1}".format(self.user, self.battle)
```

Now I need to make front-end calls via Ajax and decided that the cleanest way to work is via  a REST API ([Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)).

`/battle/3/` is an example of the url of a battle (battles are done on the page of such a url). Here `3` is the `pk` of the battle that is going on.

I know that I can get the data of the current `Battle` (via a DetailView-like API call) and the current `User` via Django REST framwork.

But **what I don't know is how I can get the contestant data (either the `SuperHero` model or `BadGuy` model) for a given user via one api call**. Could I e.g. make an api call to the `get_contestant_from_user` method of `Battle`?

Comment: The question seems a bit open ended because what you have asked is certainly possible. Once logged in, you can infer the user for the request itself.

Comment: If the user is a `SuperHero` in the current battle then he can get his contestant instance via `super_hero = user.super_hero_set.get(battle_id=3)`. Else if he is a `BadGuy` in the current battle he can get his contestant instance via `bad_guy = user.bad_guy_set.get(battle_id=3)`. The problem is that I can't know if the user is a `BadGuy` or a `SuperHero` for the current `Battle`. Only by first getting all contestants for a given battle and then looking up which one matches the user would I be able to do that. But I want to do it in one api call.

Comment: If I could only call the `get_contestant_from_user` method via the api the problem would be solved. I also don't want a `BadGuy` to be able to access any instance of any other `BadGuy`s or the `Superhero` for the current battle, while a `SuperHero` should be able to get the instance of any contestant in the battle.

Comment: I would suggest going for a simpler design. Forget the object oriented style and make one Contestant class with a character type as a choice between Good and Bad. The boosters could be a class with a ForeignKey to the Contestant.